# links with thumbnails, floated have some whitespace beneath them. How to get rid of it?

Tags: css, image, css-float, whitespace, margin

I have a simple thumbnail gallery with images floated to the left:

```
<a href=".."><img src=".." /></a>
```

However there appears to be some whitespace that isn't margin nor padding on the bottom of each link (or image). What could be the cause? How can I get rid of it?

Edit: I have set line-height to 1. This seems to get rid of most of it, however there still is a 1px space at the bottom of each image.

Edit: Adding display:block to the images seems to have solved the issue.

Comment: Can you post some more code?  The css?  Provide a link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Edit: Adding display:block to the images seems to have solved the
>   issue.

That works. Another fix is `vertical-align: top`.

The "whitespace" is actually the gap reserved for descenders in letters like `g` and `j`, because the `img`s are `inline` elements.

Answer (score 0):

- Try setting the document to XHTML transitional
- Try adding a `<br/>` right before the `</a>`

Answer (score 0):

it is likely the font size spacing that the browser applies try making the image and anchor display block, then the margin and padding we work ( this is a fairly new way for FF to  apply line height)